# Что то не так с синтаксисом Codeigniter. Помогите!

Tags: php, codeigniter

Когда залогинен - все работает корректно. Если страницу просматриваю без логина - получаю

> Message: Trying to get property of non-object.

**controler:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Payment extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("user_model");

        // If the user does not have premium. 
        // -1 means they have unlimited premium
        if($this->settings->info->global_premium && 
            ($this->user->info->premium_time != -1 && 
                $this->user->info->premium_time < time()) ) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("globalmsg", lang("success_29"));
            redirect(site_url("funds/plans"));
        }
    }

    public function go($username="") 
    {
        if(empty($username)) $this->template->error(lang("error_51"));

        $user = $this->user_model->get_user_by_username($username);
        if($user->num_rows() == 0) $this->template->error(lang("error_52"));
        $user = $user->row();

        if($user->user_role == -1) $this->template->error(lang("error_53"));

        $groups = $this->user_model->get_user_groups($user->ID);

        $this->template->set_layout("layout/pay_layout.php");
        $this->template->loadContent("payment/go.php", array(
            "user" => $user,
            "groups" => $groups
            )
        );
    }

}

?>
```

View:

```
<!-- Page Header -->
                <div class="content bg-gray-lighter">
                    <h1 class="page-heading push">
                        Счет №8788 - На чашечку кофе команде  <?php echo $user->credit_card ?> **// Здесь нормально появляется переменная**
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <!-- END Page Header -->

                <!-- Page Content -->
                <div class="content content-boxed">
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php if($this->user->info->disable_credit_card) : ?> // здесь не знаю как правильно указать
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pp" class="block block-rounded block-link-hover3">
                                <div class="block-content block-content-full clearfix">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        <img class="img-avatar enter" src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/onui/assets/img/pay/card.png" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        <div class="font-w600 push-5">Банковские карты</div>
                                        <div class="text-muted">Комиссия 0%</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END Page Content -->
```

Итак, вот такой код сработал, но ситуация стала следующей: если юзер незалогинен, видит блок корректно, если залогинен - для него все наоборот:

```html
<?php if($user->disable_credit_card) : ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pp" class="block block-rounded block-link-hover3">
                                <div class="block-content block-content-full clearfix">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        <img class="img-avatar enter" src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/onui/assets/img/pay/card.png" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        <div class="font-w600 push-5">Банковские карты</div>
                                        <div class="text-muted">Комиссия 0%</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($user->disable_yandex_money) : ?>
```

где `<?php if($user->disable_credit_card) : ?>` - вкл/выкл. блока.

то есть не залогинен и отмечено, что блок выключен - юзер видит его включенным.

Comment: где строка на которой произошол варнинг и что там вообще,

Comment: <?php if($this->user->info->disable_credit_card) : ?> - это вкл/выключение блока.

Comment: $disable_credit_card = intval($this->input->post("disable_credit_card")); // Вкл/выкл Банковские карты в контролере аккаунта

Comment: у вас где-то вместо объекта приходит null/boolean/etc

Comment: как сказал Etki дампите через var_dump и смотрите от куда пришла переменная

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Всем спасибо за подсказки.
Все работает при таком синакси

```html
<?php if($user->disable_credit_card) : ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pp" class="block block-rounded block-link-hover3">
                                <div class="block-content block-content-full clearfix">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        <img class="img-avatar enter" src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/onui/assets/img/pay/card.png" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        <div class="font-w600 push-5">Банковские карты</div>
                                        <div class="text-muted">Комиссия 0%</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
```